# Python pyTelegramBotAPI как изменить шрифт?

Tags: python, telebot

В телеграмме есть шрифт Fixedsys 
Как его использовать боту при отправки сообщения?

Comment: разве в телеграмме можно менять шрифт?

Comment: [Возможно это имелось ввиду?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49327296/how-can-i-write-bold-in-python-telegram-bot)

Comment: Да!я это имел ввиду